# PhpMyAdmin set SQL query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am having a problem with phpMyAdmin. So the case is there are 2 different table for example Intake and Courses. Courses have Intake ID as a Foreign Key and i create a column called "CoursesIntake" in Courses and later on i want to take "IntakeName" value from intake table into "CoursesIntake". I already create the InnerJoin statement but, whenever i try to edit "IntakeID" from **Courses** Table, ***CoursesIntake*** is not updated and i must re-enter the sql query again. Anyone can help me? so later if i update the IntakeID, CoursesIntake will be update automatically without re-enter the sql query.

Here is the SQL query

```
UPDATE courses 
INNER JOIN intake ON intake.intakeID = courses.IntakeID
SET courses.CoursesIntake = intake.IntakeName
```

Comment: the feature you want to implement is a bit against of concept of keys and foreign keys. In 99% cases you should never update `id` if it is primary key. Can you tell me why do you need to update original `id` value?

Comment: hmm i mean is like every time i insert a new data into "Courses" table, i want the CoursesIntake is automatically set based on "Courses Intake ID".  Now i must re-enter the sql query above to update my CoursesIntake

Comment: I think the problem is just on the CoursesIntake  definition of the foreign keys. Are they set as CASCADE? If I understand it right.

Comment: @JorgeCampos so i must set CoursesIntake as foreign key too? since i have IntakeID in "Courses" table

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood your question. I totally agree with @Alex, if you have `Courses have Intake ID` you don't need at all the `CoursesIntake` everytime you need it, just join both tables. This is not a good normalization.